# One socket descriptor always blocked on write. Select not working?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Hello I have a server program and a client program. The server program is working fine, as in I can telnet to the server and I can read and write in any order (like a chat room) without any issue. However I am now working on my client program and when I use 'select' and check if the socket descriptor is set to read or write, it always goes to write and then is blocked. As in messages do not get through until the client sends some data.

How can I fix this on my client end so I can read and write in any order?

```
 while (quit != 1)
 {
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_ZERO(&write_fds);

    FD_SET(client_fd, &read_fds);
    FD_SET(client_fd, &write_fds);

    if (select(client_fd+1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, NULL) == -1) 
    {
        perror("Error on Select");
        exit(2);
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(client_fd, &read_fds))
    {
        char newBuffer[100] = {'\0'};
        int bytesRead = read(client_fd, &newBuffer, sizeof(newBuffer));
        printf("%s",newBuffer);
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(client_fd, &write_fds))
    {
        quit = transmit(handle, buffer, client_fd);
    }
}
```

Here is code to transmit function

```
int transmit(char* handle, char* buffer, int client_fd)
{

    int n;
    printf("%s", handle);
    fgets(buffer, 500, stdin);

    if (!strchr(buffer, '\n'))
    {
       while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
    }

    if (strcmp (buffer, "\\quit\n") == 0)
    {
       close(client_fd);
       return 1;
    }
    n = write(client_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0)
    {
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    }

    memset(buffer, 0, 501);
}
```

Comment: 'Messages do not get through until the client sends some data'. Of course not.  Your point?

Comment: Could you please post your complete server and client code.

Comment: Did you remember to set the socket non-blocking? Also, can you explain why you are adding the socket to the write set? Why do you care whether the socket is writable or not?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misinterpreting the use of the `writefds` parameer of select(): only set the bit when you *want* to write data to the socket. In other words, if there is no data, do not set the bit.

Setting the bit will check if there is room for writing, and if yes, the bit will remain on. Assuming you are not pumping megabytes of data, there will always be room, so right now you will always call `transmit()` which waits for input from the command line with `fgets()`, thus blocking the rest of the program. You have to monitor both the client socket and stdin to keep the program running.

So, check for READ action on stdin (use STDIN_FILENO to get the file descriptor for that), READ on client_fd always and just write() your data to the client_fd if the amount of data is small (if you need to write larger data chunks consider non-blocking sockets).

BTW, you forget to return a proper value at the end of transmit().

Comment: You should only select for write when a prior send has returned EWOULDBLOCK. Otherwise when you have something to write you should just write. There's no point in selecting on a condition which is almost always true.

Answer (score 0):

select is used to check whether a socket has become ready to read or write. If it is blocking for read then that indicates no data to read. If it is blocking in write, then that indicates the TCP buffer is likely full and the remote end has to read some data so that the socket will allow more data to be written. Since the select blocks until one of the socket descriptions is ready, you also need to use timeout in select to avoid waiting for a long time.

In your specific case, if your remote/receiving end keep reading data from the socket then the select will not block for the write on the other end. Otherwise the tcp buffer will become full on the sender side and select will block. Answers posted also indicate the importance of handling EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.

Sample flow:

```
while(bytesleft > 0)
then
    nbytes = write data
    if(nbytes > 0)
      bytesleft -= nbytes;
    else
      if write returns with EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK
        call poll or select to wait for the socket to be come ready
       endif
    endif
    if poll or select times out
       then handle the timeout error(e.g. the remote end did not send the
                                      data within expected time interval)
    endif
end while
```

The code also should include handle error conditions and read/write returning with (For example, write/read returning with 0). Also note read/recv returning 0 indicates the remote end closed the socket.

Comment: If `select()` says the socket is writable than the socket buffer is not full. However, if you try to write more than the socket has space for, it will block if you are using a blocking socket until enough space becomes available.

Comment: right. But if the socket is blocked i.e. if select does not return then that indicates the socket is not ready for write. There might be different reason,  but likely the tcp buffer is full or some other reason.

Comment: If `select()` is blocked, then the socket is not readable, either. There is no problem when the socket has no work to do.

Comment: Blocking in `send()` indicates that the send buffer is *definitely* full. There is no other explanation.

Comment: The 'sample flow' should just consist of select and then read if readable, without the prior read.

Comment: Thx. Modified to include a loop and also replaced read with write.

Comment: All that is just an elaborate way of implementing a blocking write. It's basically pointless. The idiom is to have a select loop that tells the program what to do next, not a series of selects inside other loops.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are almost always writable, except when the socket send buffer is full, which indicates that you are sending faster than the receiver is receiving.

So your `transmit()` function will be entered every time around the loop, so it will read some data from `stdin,` which blocks until you type something, so nothing happens.

You should only select on writability when a prior `send()` has returned EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN. Otherwise you should just send, when you have something to send.

I would throw this code away and use two or three threads in blocking mode.